# Nuxt plugin imports abuse vendors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, datepicker, nuxt.js

I am trying to use `vuejs-datepicker` in a nuxt app, everything is done by nuxt plugin usage standarts.

`plugins/vue-datepicker.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'

Vue.component('Datepicker', Datepicker)
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: [
  { src: '~/plugins/vue-datepicker', ssr: false }
],
```

But even when it is not used I am getting its dist uploaded in the `vendors/app....js` after the build. How can make nuxt create a separate chunk for it and import that chunk only in the pages which are using it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were trying to find a way to split the component from `vendor` but you were getting a `document is not defined` error you can use this syntax to import your component, it will create a separate chunk with your component and use it only in client-side.

```
components: {
  Datepicker: () => import('vue-datepicker')
}
```

Also, it would be helpful to wrap your component in `<client-only>` tag for most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

So yeah, there is basically a feature request [open](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6995) for this kind of use-case.

But looking at the Nuxt lifecycle, it looks like the plugins are imported even before the VueJS instance is done. So, you cannot lazy load it if it's done ahead of Vue.

But, you can totally import `vuejs-datepicker` on the page itself, rather than on the whole project. This may be enough

```js
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker' // then simply use `Datepicker` in the code below
```

If it's not, you can maybe try this solution: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2727#issuecomment-362213022

```js
// plugins/my-plugin
import Vue from 'vue'
export default () => {
  // ...
  Vue.use(....)
}

// adminLayouts
import myPlugin from '~/plugins/my-plugin'
export default {
  created() {
    myPlugin()
  }
}
```

So, the downside is that you have to import the component each time that you need it rather than having it globally but it also allows you to load it only on the concerned pages too and have it chunked per page/component.

Comment: With regular import, I was getting a `document not defined` error even after wrapping it in `client-only` tag. But I think that is unrelated, anyway thanks for your answe!

Answer (score 1):

The plugin I was trying to import used `window`. For this reason, any other suggested workaround still caused nuxt to crash or error in my case. I searched the whole wide web and the solution below is the only one that allows my app to run.

Instead of importing the plugin with an ES6 import, you can import it in your mounted hook, which should run in the client only. So:

```
async mounted() {
  const Datepicker = await import('vuejs-datepicker');
  Vue.use(Datepicker);
}
```

I do not know about the specific plugin you are trying to use, but in my case I had to call `Vue.use()` on the default property of the plugin, resulting in `Vue.use(MyPlugin.default)`.